# Magento cart redirects to onepage checkout, how do I make it stop?

Tags: redirect, magento, checkout, cart

Hi I'm new to Magento, so we installed the Magento Simple checkout which is working fine but when you add a product it takes you to the cart (checkout/cart) which is fine but then it suddenly jumps to (checkout/onepage).

Both pages look pretty similar except the cart page gives me the option to keep shopping and change cart quantities and update the cart while the checkout page doesn't have this. I can never change the cart options because it always redirects.

Is there anyway to stop it from redirecting? I don't even know where to start to look so I could paste some code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Simple Checkout](http://www.magentocheckout.com/) is designed to do exactly that. If you don't like it, uninstall it. If you think there is a bug, contact the authors of Simple Checkout directly.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I checked the demo on their site :

Comment: http://www.magentocheckout.com/demo/ and it doesn't jump, it stays in the cart. The 6 month support is over because the software was bought a while ago.

Comment: sure, http://metrotemplate.com/ you can select a free template then add it to cart and then you'll see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript problem. If you view the source of [checkout/cart/](http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/cart/) (difficult, I know, it tries to redirect quite quickly) you might find this in it.

```
var checkout = new Checkout(accordion,{
    progress: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/cart/progress/',
    review: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/cart/review/',
    saveMethod: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/cart/saveMethod/',
    failure: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/'}
);
```

Basically it tries to POST an update to `checkout/cart/saveMethod/` which is equivalent to the first step of onepage checkout. Unfortunately that URL doesn't exist, it should be POSTing to `checkout/onepage/saveMethod/` in the background, instead it gets a 404 error which triggers the page to reload as the "failure" URL.

The final step is `checkout/` redirects automatically to `checkout/onepage/`.

I cannot tell why the extension has started outputting URLs that begin with `checkout/cart/*` rather than `checkout/onepage/*`. Perhaps there is an admin setting somewhere? Maybe some over-enthusiastic template editing 'corrected' the file "template/checkout/onepage.phtml"? Or maybe Simple Checkout depends on overriding `Mage_Checkout_CheckoutController` and another, recent extension has it's own override which is conflicting..?

Comment: Thank you so much. that worked and the cart doesn't jump anymore. I changed:
saveMethod: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/cart/saveMethod/',
to:
saveMethod: 'http://metrotemplate.com/checkout/onepage/saveMethod/',

Unfortunately now I'm having some other problems, If I try to checkout in the cart, when I click Place Order it stays processing and nothing happens. If I go to checkout and try to checkout then I get a validation error and it was working fine before. I'll see if I can figure it out or else I'll ask for some more help :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out why in the cart if you click place order it stays there processing. Also in the checkout I'm still getting the validation error but if I click place order again the order goes through. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: When I look at the site's demo it too is POSTing to `/checkout/cart/...` which means that is intentional and that there must be a custom `CartController` for the extension. If it is not working then another extension is probably trying to define it's own controller in the same space and so is conflicting. Try to think what has changed since it was last working, did you install anything new?

Comment: There is a CartController and a OnePageController that come with the extension. I checked and they seem correctly placed. Nothing new was installed. Maybe I should re install the extension since I didn't initially install it myself.

Comment: Re-installing won't hurt. And maybe the person who originally did it can lend some assistance too.

Comment: I reinstalled but it worked the same as in the beginning with the jumping shopping cart. Now I really don't know what to do because I always thought the installation was wrong but now I know it's correct. The instructions say to erase the contents of var/cache and also cookies which I have done several times.

Comment: What I mean is if I copy the code that shows the cart from cart.phtml to onepage.phtml then I get an error. I'm guessing that onepage doesn't load the cart variables like cart.phtml does. So if I could load the cart variables in the onepage checkout then I guess that would work.